# What was the correlation between a US state's Hispanic population and two party vote share for Hillary Clinton?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, statistics, demographics

I was thinking about what the correlation between two variables would be. Namely these are the percent Hispanic in a state and the percent non third party voting Democratic in the 2016 election. What is the correlation between those two variables?

I tried to answer on my own but I felt it would be easier to ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the latest available (2018) data from the [American Community Survey](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs), we can plot the percentage of a state's population identifying as Hispanic against that state's [two-party vote share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state) for Clinton.

The Pearson correlation coefficient of the two variables is ~0.3, indicating a weak positive correlation.

[image]